# oauth2 access token expire

Tags: php, google-oauth

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Google/src/Google/autoload.php');

/************************************************
  ATTENTION: Fill in these values! Make sure
  the redirect URI is to this page, e.g:
  http://localhost:8080/user-example.php
 ************************************************/
 $client_id = 'xxxxx-1l76cd2vi4ik5oqm5s20nj965riu4hum.apps.googleusercontent.com';
 $client_secret = 'secret';
 $redirect_uri = 'http://www.audit.polydevs.co.uk/oauth2callback.php?login';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setScopes('email');

/************************************************
  If we're logging out we just need to clear our
  local access token in this case
 ************************************************/

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
  header("Location: login.php");
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logoutInvalid'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    header("Location: login.php?invalid");
}

/************************************************
  If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
  we need to exchange that with the authenticate()
  function. We store the resultant access token
  bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

/************************************************
  If we have an access token, we can make
  requests, else we generate an authentication URL.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

/************************************************
  If we're signed in we can go ahead and retrieve
  the ID token, which is part of the bundle of
  data that is exchange in the authenticate step
  - we only need to do a network call if we have
  to retrieve the Google certificate to verify it,
  and that can be cached.
 ************************************************/
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
}

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug
  $client->authenticate;
  $newAccessToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
  $client->refreshToken($newAccessToken->refresh_token);
}

if (strpos($client_id, "googleusercontent") == false) {
  echo missingClientSecretsWarning();
  exit;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['login'])) {
    if (isset($authUrl)) {
        header('Location:'.$authUrl);
    } else {
        require_once('func/connect.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $token_data['payload']['email']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0) {           
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            $plus = new Google_Service_Plus( $client );
            $me = $plus->people->get('me');

            $query = "INSERT INTO users (name,email,role) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $me['displayName']);
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $token_data['payload']['email']);
            $stmt->bindValue(3, 'regular');
            $stmt->execute();

            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically here

```
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug
  $client->authenticate;
  $newAccessToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
  $client->refreshToken($newAccessToken->refresh_token);
}
```

Once my token expires, I cannot logout nor access any of the webpages as they require to have a valid token..

nor can i login, as that requires it too!

Or alternatively, can I just disable it!

EDIT

I'm very sorry, I'm tired and assuming everyone knows what I'm talking about.. The issue is that when the access token expires, I can either unset the $_SESSION['access_token'] and force relogging in ( major problem ) or have a way of just refreshing / disabling the token/expire so it won't impede on any ongoing processes for the user.

Comment: Could you give more details describing your problem (in English, not only code)? As it stands, I have to make many inferences just to know what you are asking. Someone less patient than me might have the answer you seek.

Comment: @jpaugh I'm very sorry, I'm tired and assuming everyone knows what I'm talking about.. The issue is that when the access token expires, I can either unset the $_SESSION['access_token'] and force relogging in ( major problem ) or have a way of just refreshing / disabling the token/expire so it won't impede on any ongoing processes for the user.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't have your answer. I'm only vaguely aware of OAuth, myself. But I am aware that well-worded questions get more attention. Good luck!

Comment: Remember client_id must remain private I have edited your question and removed it for you.

Comment: Access tokens expire they are short lived normally an hour, you either need to prompt the user for access again or save the refreshtoken someplace so that you can use it to get a new access token.  this would depend upon what your application is doing and wither or not you need access to there data when they are not online.

Comment: @DalmTo Actually the `client_id` is considered public knowledge. It is used to build login urls and in client side APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading a basic guide about OAuth so you can get the general idea.

Basically the server and the client go through a series of steps to prove that they are who they say they are. Once this has been completed the server will issue a short lived `access_token` and a `refresh_token`.

You can then use this `access_token` in all Api requests. However this `access_token` has a limited lifetime. When it expires you must give the `refresh_token` to the server and it will issue another `access_token`

To do this with the Google Api PHP library you use this code

```
//$client is the GApi Client
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    echo 'Access Token Expired'; // Debug
    $client->refreshToken('your_refresh_token');
}
```

Comment: Oh boy.. I guess I was very tired haha! I'll regenerate a new secret. Thank you. So, If I logically take these steps I'll be fine `user logs in->refreshtoken is stored in db under their accesstoken->isaccesstokenexpired() runs, check db for refresh token with access token->setfrefreshtoken to db refreshtoken` and we're good to go?

Comment: @danny123 I would recommend storing the `refresh_token` under the user Id. This is because the `access_token` will constantly be changing. But other than that, yea your good to go.

Comment: Thank you, I'll store it under the user id. However, I have one more question.. Sorry :P If I store it under the user id, where their name/email is stored, how will I do a comparison  with select if their token_data will be inaccessible when the token has depleted?

Comment: @Danny123 For each user just store the `access_token` associated with it and the `refresh_token`. Then when you need to get the `refresh_token`  just query the users table where the `access_token` equals the expired `access_token`. So the users table would have [`user_id`, `user_email`, `access_token`, `refresh_token`]. Then query it with `SELECT * FROM users WHERE access_token='xxxxxxxxx'`

Comment: I got it working, I was presuming that without the access token I couldn't use their current $token_data, where'as that isn't the case so it was quite easy. Thank you.